# How to model variation in different parts of a distribution and understand impact of change of one or more on overall?

Tags: r, distributions, simulation, monte-carlo, quasi-monte-carlo

I have a very large distribution of real world process values with about 200 odd attributes that can be used to divide it within different parts.

This distribution is essentially a time delta between two time stamps and is roughly normal skewed to left with long tails on either side. This distribution can be broken into ~25 odd different distributions which should be similar based on attributes (but not important to model it separately, this is just for information)

There are 2 main variables with 2 categories each. You can call these as A, B for variable 1 and 1, 2 for variable 2. Right now A, B are roughly 70 % and 30 % and 1, 2 roughly 60 % and 40 %. These are process variables and we are trying to reduce composition of A and 1. How do we model this correctly so that i can understand how the overall distribution changes.

Presently Var1-> A:70 % B: 30%,   Var2 -> 1:60 % 2:40 % , Distribution -> Eqn1

Model and Predict sample scenarios

1. Var1-> A:60 % B: 40%,   Var2 -> 1:55 % 2:45 % , Distribution -> ????
2. Var1-> A:60 % B: 40%,   Var2 -> 1:50 % 2:50 % , Distribution -> ????
3. Var1-> A:50 % B: 50%,   Var2 -> 1:45 % 2:55 % , Distribution -> ????
4. Var1-> A:50 % B: 50%,   Var2 -> 1:40 % 2:60 % , Distribution -> ????

I would like to do this using R and ideally have a way to control different proportions of Var1 and Var2 and a confidence level in the prediction of how the distribution changes vs. current profile

Answer (score 1):

How can a time delta, presumably positive, be skewed to the left?

Can't you just estimate separately the waiting time for the distribution of time delta in each of those categories, then add them together for your new mix?

You can estimate a distribution with for example `MASS::fitdistr`. If you have enough data, you can just use the observed waiting times and sample from those to simulate the distribution.

If you don't observe the separate waiting times, I don't see a clear way of finding out which distribution belongs to which class. You could try fitting a mixture model, guess which mixture belongs to which class and then adjust from there.

Comment: Actually it is a time difference between two different time stamps that measures a specific interval, i was thinking of sampling observed for similar proportions and see how the distribution looks like, but was not sure if that is a right approach and if something else can give me a better solution

Comment: How many observations do you have for the combinations of the main variables?